# Dimension of an affine variety V(f,g)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

For $X=V(f,g)\subset \mathbb{A}^n$ with $f, g \in k[x_1,...,x_n]$ what are the possibilities for the dimensions of $X$?

Answer (score 1):

By Krull dimension theorem, the codimension is lesser or equal to the number of defining equations.

So the dimension of X is at least $n-2$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to answer! Could you expand on this a little I'm still not sure I understand. Does this mean that $dim(X)\geq 2$?

Comment: if a variety has codimension k in A^n, then it has dimension n-k.

Comment: Ah so that means that $X$ has dimension $dim(X)\leq n-2$?

Comment: @Michael , fixed. thx! The dimension is greater or equal to $n-2$.